# Ruby on Rails Assets are not loading with Nitrious.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nitrousio

I have an existing app working on Nitrous.io, but when I preview it, the html loads, but not the assets, i.e. the images, javascripts etc do not load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the Nitrous.io support team, I found the answer to this.

In your `config/environments/development.rb` file, you need to set the config variable,asset_host, that tells the app where to load the assets. For example if your ip address of the nitrious.io preview page is `http://test-rails-xyz.apse2.actionbox.io/` then:

> config.asset_host = 'http://test-rails-xyz.apse2.actionbox.io/'